# Give file name when download something from amazon s3

Tags: apex, visualforce, webservices, sandbox

*I am Integrating amazon s3. i have successfully done but the problem is file name is not coming which i want.* 
**code is here for file name.**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use iframe instead of anchor tag it will resolve your issue

Comment: Hi, welcome to the community and thank you for your answer. Could you leave a more complet answer, perhaps with some sample code, to help the user?